# Explain why discontinuous function is Riemann-Integrable

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

I am supposed to find an increasing function on the interval $\left[0, 1\right]$ that is discontinuous for $x \in \{1 / n\}_{n = 2}^{\infty}$ and then explain directly why it is Riemann-Integrable.

I know that a function is Riemann-Integrable if $f$ is bounded on $\left[a, b\right]$ and $I_* = I^*$, where $I_*$ is the least upper bound of the set of values $L(f, P)$ for various partitions P and $I^*$ is the greatest lower bound for the set of values of $U(f, P)$ for various partitions P.

Wondered if someone had a simple example of this to show me? My professor said there is a lot of functions to choose from, but the way to explain it would be the same for all of them. The definition that I wrote here makes sense to me, can't really refer to much else.

Comment: Your $f$ is not increasing.

Comment: wow, true! hmm any suggestion for another f? I suck at this

Comment: How about $$f(x) = \frac{1}{n}, x \in \left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right], n=1,2,3\cdots$$

Comment: How about you set up jump discontinuities?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri what is that? I am early in a very basic calculus course and don't really have the knowledge nor the tools nor the possibility to refer to anything outside of what we have learned, which is basically what I mentioned here and also proofs involving $\epsilon - \delta$

Comment: @saulspatz I dont understand that function. Is it discontinuous for $x \in \{1 / n\}_{n = 2}^{\infty}$ only on the interval $[0, 1]$?

Comment: The function I suggested has jump discontinuities at the points $1/n$.  If $x$ approaches the point from the left or from the right, there's a limit, but the two limits aren't the same.  If you look at any point in the interval other than $1/n,$ it lies in a small interval where the function is constant, and certainly continuous.  If you still don't see this, I suggest you graph the function on $(1/5,1].$

Comment: @saulspatz I just dont get how to use that function, where is $x$?

Comment: $x$ doesn't appear.  The function is constant on intervals.  It's like the step functions you saw when the Riemann integral was developed, only it has infinitely may steps.

Comment: @DavidReed Not quite.  A bounded function is Riemann integrable iff the set of its discontinuities has Lebesgue measure zero.  This is called "Lebesgue's criterion," I believe.  Any countable set has measure 0, but there are uncountable sets of measure 0, too.

Comment: @saulspatz ah yes, continuous a.e. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: It is much simpler (compared to proof of integrability of continuous functions) to prove that any monotone function is Riemann integrable on any closed interval. Use the criterion of integrability based on difference between upper and lower Darboux sums. As to the example of such a function the one given by @saulspatz is the simplest.